# NodeJS: How check if a class/stub is called with new?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I have the following code, which is used to start device command class.

```
class DeviceCommand {

  /**
   * DeviceCommand constructor.
   *
   * @param  {String} cmd - The command to send.
   * @param  {String} ack - The acknowledgement from the device.
   */
  constructor(cmd, ack) {

    if (arguments.length !== 2) {
      throw new Error('Expected at least 2 paramters');
    }

    this.cmd = cmd;
    this.ack = ack;
  }

}
```

I would like to test if the class is called with new, using the following

```
const ClassStub = sandbox.spy(() => sinon.createStubInstance(DeviceCommand));
ClassStub.should.have.been.calledWithNew;
```

However, this is not actually performing the test as the following also passes

```
ClassStub.should.not.have.been.calledWithNew;
```

while, the following fails

```
sinon.assert.calledWithNew(ClassStub);
```

Is this not supposed to be done like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a constructor function was called with `new` requires wrapping the constructor function in a spy and then verifying that the spy was called with `new`.

Here is a simple example:

**lib.js**

```
class DeviceCommand { }

module.exports = {
  DeviceCommand
};
```

**lib.test.js**

```
const lib = require('../src/lib');
const sinon = require('sinon');

it('should verify that DeviceCommand was called with new', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(lib, 'DeviceCommand');
  const instance = new lib.DeviceCommand();
  sinon.assert.calledWithNew(spy);  // Success!
})
```

Comment: In your solution, the following

`const instance = new lib.DeviceCommand();`
 actually calls the stub with New. Is this test useful then?